# How do I get a Genius iLook 300 webcam to work?

Tags: 10.04, webcam

please help me install webcam Genius iLook 300 v1.4 in ubuntu 10.04.
lsusb show this:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2628 Pixart Imaging, Inc.
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so I noticed a question that needed an answer. This one is one of those weaker points when it comes to linux not a problem as such you just need to look a bit deeper for a solution. So I eventually found a blog half in French half in English lucky as my french is basic. [Stemp Blog on gspca drivers](http://stemp.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/karmic-get-the-latest-drivers-for-gspca-uvc-usbvideo-and-other/)

It is quite a technical walk through and it is for Karmic 9.10 but not everything in Linux changes that fast (if it ain't broke don't fix it) and I have seen a few mentions of people using the same process in Lucid 10.04, so it should be fine to use the process in Maverick 10.10. One Final comment that is mentioned later in the blog post is that not all programs use v4l2 and you will need to force them to use v4l1 compatabilty module using this command eg.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

Instead of just

```
skype
```

Just means you will need to update a few short cuts. Had a similar problem with a creative webcam so its not unique.

Hope this helps